# Modify arrays within objects in jq

Tags: json, jq

I have an array of objects, and want to filter the arrays in the `b` property to only have elements matching the `a` property of the object.

```json
[
  {
    "a": 3,
    "b": [
      1,
      2,
      3
    ]
  },
  {
    "a": 5,
    "b": [
      3,
      5,
      4,
      3,
      5
    ]
  }
]
```

produces

```json
[
  {
    "a": 3,
    "b": [
      3
    ]
  },
  {
    "a": 5,
    "b": [
      5,
      5
    ]
  }
]
```

Currently, I've arrived at

```
[.[] | (.a as $a | .b |= [.[] | select(. == $a)])]
```

That works, but I'm wondering if there's a better (shorter, more readable) way.

Comment: I'd use `map(...)` instead of `[.[] | ...]`. Though not sure what you mean by *better*; better how?

Comment: @oguzismail shorter or more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two ways to do this with less code and both are variants of what you have already figured out on your own.

1. ```
    map(.a as $a | .b |= map(select(. == $a)))
   ```
2. ```
    del(.[] | .a as $a | .b[] | select(. != $a))
   ```